# How to get index value in combo box?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ComboBox with two values 'cash' and 'bank' if the user selects bank I need to enable two controls. I've tried below code:

```
private void comboBox_pay_type_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox_bank.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            comboBox_bank.Enabled = true;
            textBox_recp_no.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Problem is the index value is -1 for both cash and bank. Where have I made an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just referencing the wrong combo box:

```
private void comboBox_pay_type_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox_pay.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        comboBox_bank.Enabled = true;
        textBox_recp_no.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

You need to reference `comboBox_pay` here.

Answer (score 0):

Use selectedItem.Index, it gets set after the following event is triggered:

The SelectedItem property is a proper member of the ComboBox control. The event that is fired on change is ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted

```
ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted
```